# How to use an alias in a subquery in SurrealDB?

Tags: sql, alias, surrealdb

I was using the starter dataset SurrealDB supplied and working with the `daily_sales` table. The goal was to query the table and format the result to show the `best_sales` and `best_day` grouped by the `month_year`. While I was able to use the `<datetime>` casting to format the string into dates and find the max value of the sales to find the best sales in the month, it appeared that finding the day when the best sales happened seemed trickier. I need to equate the result of the grouping sales to the individual days of each sale from the initial `daily_sales` table. Using a subquery when building the table out in the `SELECT` clause would not retain the aliases from the main query.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also show us your current SQL attempt.

Comment: @jarlh - You're right. At the time it wasn't in my head but after looking at it sometime later, I see the necessity in having the problem written out. Thank you for that notice.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that creating the table within the `FROM` cause did the trick of being able to use the aliases and also use the `$parent` variable name.

My final result is this:

```sql
select *,
(select value day from only daily_sales where sum_sales = $parent.best_sales) as best_day from (
select time::format(<datetime> day, "%B-%Y") as month_year,
math::max(sum_sales) as best_sales
from daily_sales
group by month_year
)
```

I used `value` and `only` to return a single value without any array. The `$parent` preset variable helped retain the `best_sales` variable when compared to the original `daily_sales` table.

The final result looked like this:

```json
[
  {
    "result": [
      {
        "best_day": "2023-04-11",
        "best_sales": 971548.94,
        "month_year": "April-2023"
      },
      {
        "best_day": "2023-08-04",
        "best_sales": 902987.03,
        "month_year": "August-2023"
      },
      {
        "best_day": "2023-12-27",
        "best_sales": 810232.31,
        "month_year": "December-2023"
      },
      {
        "best_day": "2023-02-02",
        "best_sales": 872801.88,
        "month_year": "February-2023"
      },
      {
        "best_day": "2023-01-10",
        "best_sales": 887891.61,
        "month_year": "January-2023"
      },
      {
        "best_day": "2023-07-15",
        "best_sales": 858560.62,
        "month_year": "July-2023"
      },
      {
        "best_day": "2023-06-04",
        "best_sales": 883341.91,
        "month_year": "June-2023"
      },
      {
        "best_day": "2023-03-09",
        "best_sales": 895781.43,
        "month_year": "March-2023"
      },
      {
        "best_day": "2023-05-07",
        "best_sales": 772227.44,
        "month_year": "May-2023"
      },
      {
        "best_day": "2023-11-06",
        "best_sales": 868215.08,
        "month_year": "November-2023"
      },
      {
        "best_day": "2023-10-06",
        "best_sales": 866574.4,
        "month_year": "October-2023"
      },
      {
        "best_day": "2023-09-13",
        "best_sales": 863761.81,
        "month_year": "September-2023"
      }
    ],
    "status": "OK",
    "time": "34.672708ms"
  }
]
```

[Link to GitHub Discussion (copied from there)](https://github.com/orgs/surrealdb/discussions/1434)

[SurrealDB document on params](https://docs.surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/parameters)

[Github Discussion on using the `$parent` variable correctly](https://github.com/orgs/surrealdb/discussions/1372)